# Can I have two UK visas simultaneously?

Tags: visas, uk

I have a visitor UK visa valid until October 2017.

I also want to apply for a Tier 4 student visa. My studies in the UK start in September 2017.

If I apply for the student visa in June, will they simply issue an overlapping student visa, or will they cancel my visitor visa and I will not be able to come to the UK until September?

I am worried because in a similar situation with Schengen visas, my existing visa was canceled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK works like Schengen does in that overlapping time periods are not allowed. This is a matter of policy and not spelled out in the rules. The policy is that only one type of permission can be valid at a time.

What happens is that the issuing post will curtail the existing visa so that it ends before the new one starts.

Comment: My interpretation of this is, his original visa is valid until October, the new visa is valid from September. Therefore the original visa will remain valid until September where it will be canceled and then the student visa will become valid.
I do expect he will need to leave the UK before the visitor visa expires and then return after the student visa starts. Leaving the UK would include traveling to France or Ireland.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on this?

"the issuing post will curtail the existing visa"

My visitor visa (including the expiry date) is printed on my paper travel passport. They won't print another visitor visa just to cut the term, will they? Or will it be purely in their database? In that case, will I be notified of that change?

Comment: @FawziWasim they will record it in the database and make an endorsement on the face of your existing visa that changes its end date.