# Traveling during the wrap-up period

Tags: visas, uk

I’m a PhD student in UK with T4 visa, along with my husband and children who are dependents holding T4 dependent visas.

After getting the award letter, during the wrap-up period and before my visa expires, I plan to visit my country for three days to do some job interviews.  I also want to leave my children with my husband at UK since it will be school time.

I’ve been advised to enter the UK using a visitor visa instead of using my T4, even its still valid, as I already finished my course.

If I applied to a visitor visa would this mean that my T4 visa will be cancelled?

What will happen to my husband and children in this case (would their visas be cancelled as well even if they remained in the UK)?

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. I did it and I was detained.

Answer (score 4):

As [@GayotFow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92292/can-i-have-two-uk-visas-simultaneously/92356#92356) has recently explained, by policy, the UK allows only a single type of visa at a time, similar to Schengen visa issuance. So, yes, the T4 would become spent when a Standard Visitor Visa is issued.

The wrap-up period is intended to allow students to remain in the UK whilst making their preparations to leave the country. As you were advised, it is risky to leave and attempt to re-enter the UK during this period on the Tier 4 visa, as your reason no longer matches the purpose of the visa (i.e. to study).

Once your Tier 4 leave is cancelled, so will your dependant’s leave be cancelled (unless there are otherwise exceptional circumstances, and staying for the end of the children's school term is generally not such an exception). However, their wrap-up period would be similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

"... I plan to visit my country for three days to do some job interviews"

Ask the interviewers if you can do phone/Skype interviews.  These can be followed up with face-to-face interviews later, giving you longer with your family.